Any faster and memory-efficient alternative of torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model.decoder, latent_l)?
I have a decoder model.decoder, which is comprised of a series of Convolutional Batchnorm and ReLU layers. I have a latent vector latent_l, which is a 8 dimensional latent vector, say, has the dimension (1, 8, 1, 1), where 1 is the batch size. I am doing torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model.decoder, latent_l), which is taking a huge amount of time, is there any fast approximation for this jacobian?
There is jacrev, but I am not sure if that works for this example where we pass a decoder as a whole and compute the jacobian of the decoder with respect to the latent vector.
When I use torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model.decoder, latent_l, vectorize=True), the memory consumption of the GPU increases drastically, leading to the crashing of the program. Is there any efficient way of doing this using Pytorch?

Do you actually need the full jacobian or just the gradient of the latent vector?

Full Jacobian... gradient would be simple, I guess; just .grad will do? I need it to be memory efficient as well as fast.

You should figure out which you actually want. Say your decoder maps an input of shape (bs, 8, 1, 1) to an output of shape (bs, 3, H, W), the gradient of the latent vector will have shape (bs, 8, 1, 1), while the jacobian of the output with respect to the input will have shape (bs, 3, H, W, bs, 8, 1, 1) - the two tensors are quite different

Yes, of-course torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model.decoder, latent_l) gives (bs, 3, H, W, bs, 8, 1, 1) tensor, and I want this exact tensor is a very computationally efficient way....

Nevermind, this seems to work, torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model.decoder, latent_l, strategy="forward-mode", vectorize=True)

This seems to work fine: torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(model.decoder, latent_l, strategy="forward-mode", vectorize=True), where only forward passes are needed instead of computing the whole jacobian.
